# When I try to send a text message through my app the Messages screen is automatically cancelled

Tags: ios, swift, sms

I am tying to have my app take a users input to format a text message so that they can connect to an external device in the proper format through text. I have the initial setup text message working but if the user wishes to delete the geo-fence (the initial text message is responsible for setting it) they need to send a different text message however the Messages screen is automatically cancelled when called.

```
@IBAction func addGeoFencePushed(_ sender: Any) {
    if(!geoFenceIsEnabled()){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "How large would you like the geofence to be?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (_) in
            if let field = alertController.textFields?[0] {
                // store your data
                ALGlobal.sharedInstance.globalDefaults.set(field.text! as String, forKey: "geoFenceSize")
                let rad = Double(field.text!)
                ALGlobal.sharedInstance.geoFenceRadius = rad!
                self.buttonSetting = 1
                self.toggleButton()
                self.drawGeoFence(radius: rad!)
                self.turnOnFenceText(radius: Int(rad!))
            } else {
                // user did not fill field
            }
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Feet"
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        }

        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Are you sure you want to remove the geo-fence?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (_) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.removeGeoFence()
        }
        alert.addAction(confirmAction)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is what is responsible for determining which text message to display.

```
func removeGeoFence(){
    self.turnOffFenceText()
    ALGlobal.sharedInstance.globalDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "geoFenceSize")
    ALGlobal.sharedInstance.geoFenceRadius = 0
    self.buttonSetting = 0

    self.toggleButton()
    self.clearMap()
}
func turnOnFenceText(radius: Int){
    let radiusConverted = Int(radius / 3)

    messageVC.body = "G1,1,0,\(radiusConverted)M"
    messageVC.recipients = [ALGlobal.sharedInstance.globalDefaults.object(forKey: "devicePhoneNumber") as! String]
    self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func turnOffFenceText(){
    messageVC.body = "G1,0"
    messageVC.recipients = [ALGlobal.sharedInstance.globalDefaults.object(forKey: "devicePhoneNumber") as! String]
    self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.rawValue) {
    case MessageComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        messageVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Message failed")
        messageVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Message was sent")
        messageVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And these are the message controllers. When removeGeoFence() is called the console prints out "Message was cancelled" and the Messages app never opens and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are presenting  MFMessageComposeViewController object on UIAlertController first dismiss that then try to present  messageVC

Comment: @iosDev should I dismiss it in the turnOffFenceText() function? If I dismiss it after I present it wouldn't it just not show up then?

Comment: you can dismiss on  confirmAction first dismiss  alert because MFMessageComposeViewController can't present on already presented view controller

Comment: I edited the question with that change however that did not solve the problem. The message is still being cancelled without user interaction

Comment: are you testing in device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recreate the messageVC after you dismiss it otherwise your trying to reopen a dismissed view and that results in a black screen so in the turnOnFenceText() and turnOffFenceText() I reinitialized the messageVC:

```
func turnOnFenceText(radius: Int){
        messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        let radiusConverted = Int(radius / 3)

        messageVC.body = "G1,1,0,\(radiusConverted)M"
        messageVC.recipients = [ALGlobal.sharedInstance.globalDefaults.object(forKey: "devicePhoneNumber") as! String]
        self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func turnOffFenceText(){
        messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        messageVC.body = "G1,0"
        messageVC.recipients = [ALGlobal.sharedInstance.globalDefaults.object(forKey: "devicePhoneNumber") as! String]
        self.present(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

That fixed the problem